# I can't makemigrations in django 1.11.9

Tags: php, django, python-3.x

### Python3.6.5 migrations problem

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations
```

I can't makemigrations and migrate in python3 version and Django==1.11.9 -v

I have already deleted `0001_initial.py` but it doesn't work for me help me!!

---

```
DEBUG 2018-06-17 16:38:58,008 utils 5154 140704182478656 (0.000) 
            SELECT name, type FROM sqlite_master
            WHERE type in ('table', 'view') AND NOT name='sqlite_sequence'
            ORDER BY name; args=None
DEBUG 2018-06-17 16:38:58,010 utils 5154 140704182478656 (0.000) SELECT "django_migrations"."app", "django_migrations"."name" FROM "django_migrations"; args=()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/tugu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/tugu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/tugu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/tugu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/tugu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 83, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "/home/tugu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/home/tugu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/home/tugu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 274, in build_graph
    raise exc
  File "/home/tugu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 244, in build_graph
    self.graph.validate_consistency()
  File "/home/tugu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 261, in validate_consistency
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
  File "/home/tugu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 261, in <listcomp>
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
  File "/home/tugu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 104, in raise_error
    raise NodeNotFoundError(self.error_message, self.key, origin=self.origin)
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration auth.0010_auto_20180524_1306 dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('auth', '0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length')
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly, remove pyc files from your migrations folder.
if still not solved, remove that reference from frshBolt.0001_initial by editing the migration file.
if that also not worked try this solution, 
remove the new changes from models and run `python manage.py migrate --fake`. again modify your models with new changes then run `python manage.py makemigrations` and after this run `python manage.py migrate`.